# Get Data between Vertical Bars

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to extract the following data.

```
|SERVER-1|Running|SERVER-2|Running|SERVER-3|Running|
```

I would like to get the data between the vertical bars like this

```
SERVER-1
Running
SERVER-2
Running
SERVER-2
Running
```

I have tried to search on-line for an answer but the more I search the more it confuses me. The closest I got was using this `\[([^]]+)\]` but it will only select the full line.

Comment: Use a `split` on those kinds of data. It's easier. Also, what language are you using?

Comment: Whatever language you are using has to have a `split` or `explode` function.  In what language/environment are you executing this regex?

Comment: You're better off using something like `s.split('|')` and excluding the first and last elements.

Comment: *"I'm trying to extract the following data"* - sounds like maybe this data is embedded within a larger text?

Comment: I have already got the data from a powershell commmand and run it via another regex command to get rid of whitespace and replace with | symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cyborgx37 pointed out, just this should cover it:

```
[^|]+
```

If you want to complicate it for no reason whatsoever, and assuming the language you're using supports look-around, this should also work:

(if the string is something like `|SERVER-2||Running|`, and you want the middle part to actually print an empty string, you'll probably need this)

```
(?<=\|)[^|]*(?=\|)
```

**Explanation:**

`?<=` is look-behind, checking that the previous characters match.
`?=` is look-ahead, checking that the next characters match.
`[^|]` means not `|`.
`+` is one or more.
`*` is zero or more.
The `\` is to escape `|`, otherwise it means 'or'.

So you check that the previous character is `|` and the next character is `|` and the actual regex is a bunch of characters that aren't `|`.

Comment: Or just `[^|]+`. I don't really see the need for anchoring the expression with zero-width assertions.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I think you're perfectly right. I'm over-thinking things, as always.